# How can I retreive the specific objects that contains a specific string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database that contains a series of the JSON object (exercises), I would like to filter and retrieve only those that have a specific string.

my method below retrieve all of them, I provide the specific string (pathExercice) as a parameter, but I'm not sure how to use to select only the objects that contains it.

here is an example of data that I currently have on my database.
in this case, I would like to retrieve this object if my pathExercice provided in my method, matches the string inside my object

Any clues? thank you

```
-Le7BeKeG9Zes6mZ7gUm
      date: 1557063173016
      pathExercice: "DeveloppeCouche"
      reps: 10
      weight: 10
```

```
export const readUserData = async (pathExercice) => {
    let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices')
    return ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val()
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error:  ' + err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution, thx to those who have taken the time to read my post.

```
export const readUserData = async (pathExercice) => {
let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices')
return ref.orderByChild('pathExercice').equalTo(pathExercice).once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val()
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error:  ' + err);
    });
```

}

Comment: Yeah, that would work for an equality. I assumed you wanted substring matching, given the "contains a specific string" in the title, because that most frequently means folks are looking for the equivalent of SQL's `pathExercice LIKE "% Couche%"`.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database does not support wildcard string match queries, so you can't use the database to search for `pathExercice` values that *contain* a certain substring.

You **can** search for `pathExercice` that *start with* a certain substring, like this:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices')
return ref.orderByChild('pathExercice').startAt('Devel').endAt('Devel\uF7FF').once("value").then(snapshot => {
```

If you want to filter on `pathExercice` values that *contain* a certain substring, you will have to do that in your code. Note this means you'll be reading all child nodes from the database, so be mindful of how many child nodes there are.

The code should look something like this:

```
export const readUserData = async (pathExercice) => {
    let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices')
    return ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        results = [];
        snapshot.forEach(exercise => {
            if (exercise.child('pathExercice').val().indexOf('Couche') >= 0) {
                results.push(exercise.val());
            }
        }
        return results;
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error:  ' + err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Frank, it is possible to retrieve those data more simply, check my solution below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would obtain the string inside pathExercise

```
export const readUserData = async (pathExercice) => {
    let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices')
    return ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        if (snapshot.val().pathExercice === "DeveloppeCouche") {
             //some action here
        }
        return snapshot.val()
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error:  ' + err);
    });
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you Jaye, that would work as well, but i prefer to pass my path as a variable, because it could be a different string depending on where this method is called in my app, each screen has a constant with a string 'myPath:pathForThisScreen'.